# ERROR Error: Cannot set property 'text' of undefined

Tags: angular, highcharts

I run into trouble with the error: `ERROR Error: Cannot set property 'text' of undefined`
 if I wanted to change dynamical some properties in Highcharts using Angular like `options.subtitle.text = 'text';` and after this, update the chart with the "update(options)"-method.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
I found out that you have to set the properties to default like this `options.subtitle = {};` if you create the Chart, to access the properties .

I've created a Example to clarify what I mean: [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nd4svb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
**Line:56** | *set to default*
**Line:25** | *change the property and using the update-method*

Hope someone helped this information out of some problems.